# Enable input DMS option in ArcMap while georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I am a newbie to ArcMap. I tried to georeference a map in JPEG format using the "input DMS..." option. But it is grayed out, the only option available is to choose X, and Y coordinates even if the georeferencing system I chose is in degrees.

Are there any solutions except trying to convert DMS coordinates to X, and Y coordinates?

Comment: Did you mean "DSM coordinates" or DMS? DMS to DD conversion is *really* simple.

Comment: I was talking about DMS and specifically the option of adding DMS of Lon an lat when you right-click on a control point just added.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the DMS option, you need to set the Coordinate System of the Data Frame. Before opening the image, right click on the *Layers* from the *Table of Contents*. Go to *Coordinate Systems* and select the one that you need. Finally, open the image that you want to georeference and you will be able to add DMS coordinates.